# Rails specs for simple sidekiq delete worker failling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, sidekiq

I've got simple sidekiq worker which, I don't know why it doesn't worked. I think maybe it's because of specs.

`worker`

```
class AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    expired_logs = AdminPanelLog.where('created_at > ?', 1.year.ago)
    expired_logs.delete_all
  end
end
```

`specs`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe AdminPanelLogRemoverWorker do
  include_context 'with admin_user form'

  subject { described_class.new.perform }

  let!(:admin_panel_log1) do
    create :admin_panel_log,
    action_type: 'Update',
    old_data: admin_user_form,
    created_at: 2.years.ago
  end
  let!(:admin_panel_log2) do
    create :admin_panel_log,
    old_data: admin_user_form,
    created_at: 2.days.ago
  end

  context 'when admin log is outdated' do
    it 'calls remover worker' do
      expect(AdminPanelLog.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
end
```

The `admin_panel_log1` and `admin_panel_log2` is corresponding model `AdminPanelLog` and it forms correctly (maybe I should avoid `let!` ?). At the result specs failed with an error

> Failure/Error: expect(AdminPanelLog.count).to eq(1)
>   expected: 1
>   got: 0
>   (compared using ==)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I justed tested with

```
RSpec.describe TestController, type: :controller do

    subject { User.new }

    let!(:test) do
      p subject
      p "dfvb"
    end

    it 'testing order of let and subject' do 
      # Spec
     end
end
```

The `subject` is initialized before the `let!` block is called. So in your case, the lo `AdminPanelLog` is not even created while the job was running. So that the example failed.

```
context 'when the admin log is outdated' do
    it 'calls remover worker' do
      subject.new.perform #Perform the job here or after the initialization of AdminPanelLog 
      expect(AdminPanelLog.count).to eq(1)
    end
  end
```

and  remove this `subject { described_class.new.perform }`, as the subject itself will hold the value of the current class.

Comment: Or I could just leave as it is with some name like subject(:delete_worker) { described_class.new.perform }` and pass it before expect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As already transpires from the Aarthi answer, the issue was that you did not call subject, so the code was not executed and your worker was not called.
Still, I would improve the answer with the following

```
context 'when admin log is outdated' do
    it 'remover worker deletes them' do
      expect { subject }.to change(AdminPanelLog, :count).by(-2) #or whatever the amount is
    end
  end
```

The above test allows you to check if the worker indeed did it's job at deleting stuff.